# Should I tell this player her character cannot be resurrected?

Tags: dnd-5e, social-contract, curse-of-strahd, resurrection

I'm in a bit of a quandary as to what to do with a player. We're going through *Curse of Strahd* and I am DMing. Her Cleric got killed towards the beginning of the game and cannot be resurrected as there are no possibilities for this in the next session.  The players are only level 3 so don't have any resurrection spells.

The main issue is that we won't be having another D&D session for a while. Do you think I should tell her that she'll need to make a new character, or stick to the sessions and let the party find out in-game? Just don't want her wondering about it for ages.

Comment: This is for D&D fifth edition, right?

Comment: What you "should" do also seems somewhat opinion-based, though easily reworded to be more answerable here - something like "Are there any downsides to telling her she'll need to make a new character/can't be resurrected?"

Comment: I've added the social-contract tag as this is more about how to handle it at the table rather than the resurrection itself.

Comment: Hi, thanks Jason, yes it is 5th edition.

Comment: VTC on the basis of this being primarily opinion based. Perhaps a better question would be "how can I resurrect a character at level 3" or "how do I handle early player death" and things like that

Answer (score 20):

**What will she do during the next session?**
I think an important factor, her character is dead, if your answer is: “waiting for party to discover resurrection is impossible and proceed to make a new character on the spot.” I doubt it'll be fun for her; even for a Ravenlofty campaign, that's still too much. Just tell her and save everyone some time.

**But you can let her revive the character, with a twist.** 
See, Curse of Strahd has its origin in the old "Domain of Dread" Ravenloft setting, which has a lot of interesting twists. There is an adventure league document on this particular instance, letting the dark powers of Ravenloft resurrect her:

> Second, the player can choose to have the Dark Powers of Ravenloft resurrect the character for free. If the player chooses resurrection, the character returns to play at the start of the next round with full hit points and spells. However, this dark resurrection leaves the character tainted by shadow.

You can check out the full document [here](http://www.dmsguild.com/product/186573/DDAL04-Expanded-Dark-Gifts-Table-OPTIONAL-CONTENT).

But I believe you should still get consent from the player first, just personal preference.  Remember everyone's here to have fun; fun's had, mission accomplished.

Also something to remember: tension is good.  Taking away the fear of death takes away from the tension, doubly bad for a Gothic horror setting. Absolutely DO NOT resurrect her without penalty; even if said penalty is a cosmetic "taint", players will fill in the blanks and think it's something terrible.

Comment: Another option discussed in the AL DMG (found [here](http://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/ALDMGv4_print.pdf)) is using an extra, added-to-the-game hag named Jenny Greenteeth who can Raise Dead....for a price. And it probably won't be pleasant. Naturally, you can mess with the prices, have the party owe her a favor for it, or any number of other options. As the DM...if you want a PC to be raise-able...you can provide the means for them to get a Rez.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'm still relatively new this :) I shall discuss with the player whether she wants to be resurrected with a tainted gift, or if she would like to make a new character.